# Get Content and use jQuery on it

Tags: php, jquery

i hope i wasn't to stupid to use google and search engine in sof.

i try to get the content of a page (sourcecode) and filter out some urls.

i tried

```
$url = file_get_content("http://www.blablabla.bla/blabla.html");
echo $url;
```

of course it showes me the page...

but what i want is to pass this data to jquery so i can select a childnode to extrakt a exact link.

any ideas ?

i tried jquery as well

```
var url = "http://www.blablabla.bla/blabla.html";
$.get(url,function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NLBNF/)**

no results....

alert is never called :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Have your php script return the html to your page:

page.html:

```
$.get('myscript.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

myscript.php:

```
echo file_get_content("http://www.blablabla.bla/blabla.html");
```

This is called a server-side proxy, and it's one way to get around the same origin policy.

Comment: great :) had a lil type so i thought your answere doesn't really helps but it helps perfect. THX

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = file_get_content("http://www.blablabla.bla/blabla.html");

$lookingFor = '<a href="www.link.com">Link</a>';

if (strpos($url,$lookingFor) !== false)
{
    // found it
}
```

Maybe something like that? https://www.php.net/strpos